# JPA: many to many relationship not working correctly

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the two below entities, the AssignIban contains many BankAccounts, and a bankAccount belongs to one or many AssignIban.

```
@Entity
public class AssignIbanEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String assignmentIbanId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "assignIbans", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<BankAccountEntity> bankData;

    public void addBankData(BankAccountEntity bankData) {
        if (this.bankData == null) {
            this.bankData = new HashSet<>();
        }
        this.bankData.add(bankData);
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(bankData.getAssignIbans())) {
            bankData.assignIbans(new HashSet<>());
        }
        bankData.getAssignIbans().add(this);
    }
    
}

@Entity(name = "bank_datay")
public class BankAccountEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String bankDataId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "bank_account_assignment_iban", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_bank_account") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_assignment_iban") })
    private Set<AssignIbanEntity> assignIbans;
    
}
```

In my database i have the below data:

bank_data:

[image]

bank_account_assignment_iban :

[image]

With the below code i get a bankAccount with the id `8aa2afbf-f079-44a3-9940-84dd01a97f7f` and i added it to an existant assignmentIban with the id `87f6f8ac-fd51-493d-860b-f6975faea472`

```
AssignIbanEntity assignIban = assignmentIbanRepository.findById("87f6f8ac-fd51-493d-860b-f6975faea472");
bankDataEntity bankData = bankDataRepository.findById("8aa2afbf-f079-44a3-9940-84dd01a97f7f");
if (Objects.nonNull(assignIban) && Objects.nonNull(bankData)) {
    assignIban.addBankData(bankData);
    assignmentIbanRepository.save(assignIban);
}
```

the problem is that the result that i get is not correct :

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Try to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of both entities to be based on the id of each entity. This can lead to problems as you use `HashSet` and it may be affected.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos i change `Set` to `List` and `HashSet` to `ArrayList` but it's stay the same problem.

Comment: Your addBankData method should not be manipulating the collection within bankData and replacing the collection if it was empty; you should only add to it. bankData seems like it needs a very simple 'addAssignIbanEntity(AssignIbanEntity)' method that does only a null check and sets a collection if required, then add the entity to the collection. Replacing collections cause issues with change tracking and lazy semantics that should be avoided where possible. This may help, but if not, check what is actually in the entities collections before you call the addBankData method.